ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41) Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(exception, Unknown, null, null)
Inside my Flutter app I used to have sign-in with Google which was working fine and after 1 or 2 months I tested it again it doesn't work anymore and I'm trying to figure out how and why but I keep getting this message which is not even specific to something. Yes i have the same SHA-1 in firebase and google console yes i have the google-service.json updated in the correct place . (Also note that i have in firebase and google cloud a recent (less than 30 days) deleted project with the same SHA-1 key and packege name)
Here is the related code
Terminal
I/flutter (24662): Initializing Firebase
I/flutter (24662): Firebase initialized
....
**E/flutter (24662): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(exception, Unknown, null, null)**
E/flutter (24662): #0      GoogleSignInApi.getAccessToken (package:google_sign_in_android/src/messages.g.dart:250:7)
E/flutter (24662): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24662): #1      GoogleSignInAndroid.getTokens.<anonymous closure> (package:google_sign_in_android/google_sign_in_android.dart:68:15)
E/flutter (24662): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24662): #2      GoogleSignInAccount.authentication (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:95:9)
E/flutter (24662): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24662): #3      _LoginSignupPageState.signInWithGoogle (package:flutter_drive_advisor/screens/login_page.dart:66:51)
E/flutter (24662): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24662): #4      _LoginSignupPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_drive_advisor/screens/login_page.dart:210:68)
E/flutter (24662): <asynchronous suspension>

login_page.dart
Future<UserCredential?> signInWithGoogle() async {
    // Trigger the authentication flow
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

    // Obtain the auth details from the request
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser!.authentication;

    // Create a new credential
    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    // Save the user's ID to SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('userId', userCredential.user!.uid);

    // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
    return userCredential;
  }

pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.3
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.10
  autocomplete_textfield: ^2.0.1
  flutter_typeahead: ^3.2.1
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.1
  google_fonts: ^4.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  firebase_auth: ^4.19.2 #//4.17.8
  google_sign_in: ^6.2.1  
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^3.5.6
  permission_handler: ^8.1.6
  url_launcher: ^6.0.10
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.8
  location: ^4.1.1 #^4.4.0
  android_intent: ^2.0.2
  app_settings: ^4.1.1
  optimize_battery: ^0.0.4
  intl: ^0.17.0
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  firebase_core: ^2.30.0 #//2.27.0 
  collection: ^1.18.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^8.1.1+1

what I tried :
Ensure that you have correctly set up the Google Sign-In method in the Firebase console for your project.
Make sure that the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint for your Android app is correctly added in the Firebase console. You can get the SHA-1 fingerprint by running the command ./gradlew signingReport in your Android app directory.
Check that the google-services.json file is placed in the correct location, which should be the android/app directory of your Flutter project.
Make sure that you have the latest versions of the google_sign_in and firebase_core packages in your pubspec.yaml file.
Try running flutter clean and then flutter run to clean the build cache and run the app again.
UPDATE : I just let it be for some days after so much digging and it fixed itself I don't know how but it started working after 1-2 days

Does your android/build.gradle have below code ?
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // <- this one
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

There has been some updates on how to write android/app/build.gradle and android/build.gradle files in your flutter project. Check on flutter website and migrate accordingly. Hopefully, that should solve your issue.
Check this -> https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

Update your android folder by opening it as a project in Android Studio.


Yes i had that already , I just let it be for some days after so much digging and it fixed itself I don't know how but it started working after 1-2 days
